# Fluid CSS Grid structure possible?

Tags: jquery, css, grid

Short and simple version: I have a project where I need to define a DIV that will repeat horizontally and then wrap to the next row when out of space (tabular-like grid). I've seen mention of jQuery.GridLayout, but the demo/homepage is 404'd so I have no clue if this is what I'm looking for. Simply, I'm trying to achieve this:

```
Div.ItemClass   Div.ItemClass   Div.ItemClass   Div.ItemClass
Div.ItemClass   Div.ItemClass   Div.ItemClass   Div.ItemClass
...
```

The trick is that I'm forced to use the same class (I do have access to an Alternate Item template that will insert different code for each alternate item) but I need them to 'stack' horizontally until they run out of horizontal space and then 'wrap' to the next row.

Quick background - the project is inside a CMS system, and the item listing module gives me the following template files to work with inside the "list" view:

```
-Header
-Item
-Alternate Item
-Footer
```

Thoughts, ideas?

Edit: ok, so I'm a bit of an idiot and forgot rule #1 - Check your (rendered) source.  The most significant problem is that the CMS Module that is being used is 'wrapping' each template object (Header, Item, alternate, footer) inside a TD element, making a true 'wrapping div' nigh impossible. I'm glad I wasn't just going nuts because I was fairly certain nested DIVs were the right approach.

Edit #2: Ok, now I'm thinking that I can maybe pull this off with a bit of jQuery manipulation. I would need to target the Div.ItemClass and then place them inside the positioned wrapper div, possibly overlaying / replacing the exising tabular layout code (maybe used in the Header template?). As of this edit the current code that is forced when rendered is:

```
<td><!--This is Header.html --><div class="Container" /></td>
<td><!--This is Item.html --><div class="ItemName">Item 1</div></td>
<td><!--This is Alternate.html --><div class="ItemName">Item 2</div></td>
<td><!--This is Item.html --><div class="ItemName">Item 3</div></td>
<td><!--This is Footer.html -->[PAGER]</td>
```

I hope this makes sense, as I've stated earlier, alot of the tables are forced by the CMS and module system I'm having to use for this project.

Edit #3 - Managed to make it work! Added a bit of jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.ItemClass').appendTo('#ContainerID');
});
```

Simply, it grabs the Divs out of the TD elements and places them in the ContainerID I placed in the Header.html section!

Answer (score 5):

If you have fixed widths it's easy. Just put float lefts on them and arrange the width accordingly so that only X items will be on a row. Something like

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="item">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="item">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="item">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="item">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="item">lorem ipsum</div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div> <!-- just to fix the height, remove to see effect. -->
</div>
```

and style

```
.container {
   width: 500px;
}
.item {
   width: 100px; // for 5 items (without margins)
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hrm... I think I tried that, but I'll give it another whirl and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the source of my frustration... the system is wrapping each 'section' (Header, item, alternate, footer) in it's own TD, thereby breaking the wrapper div.

Comment: Can'y say I'm a fan of Table based layouts altogether... Just an opinion.

Comment: @Moshe - I agree with you completely, however I'm attempting a grid / table-like layout using CSS however it's the framework/backend of the CMS system and 3rd party module that are adding in the extra table tags.

Comment: If you add .container { overflow: auto; } you won't need the clearing div.